# Jquery cannot skipped evaluation of first json result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I want to evaluate a set of JSON results but somehow the first result is always skipped. My Jquery code is as follows:

```
function check_product_cash_discount(total_id){
        //check for cash discount
        $.ajax({
            url:siteurl+"checkout/get_cash_discount_ajax/",
            type:"POST",
            success:function(res){
                var parsed = JSON.parse(res);
                var this_product_total = $(total_id).text();
                $.each(parsed,function(k,v){                            
                    var amount = v.cash_discount_amount;
                    //console.log(v);
                    if(this_product_total >= amount){
                        $(total_id).text(v.cash_discount_percentage);   
                        console.log(amount);
                    }
                });                             
            }
        });
    }
```

The result from the AJAX call is "res" and I parsed it with JSON.parse and place in "parsed". The value(v) of the result is as follows when console.log(v) with $.each:

```
Object {cash_discount_id: "4", cash_discount_amount: "1000", cash_discount_percentage: "10"}
Object {cash_discount_id: "3", cash_discount_amount: "800", cash_discount_percentage: "8"}
Object {cash_discount_id: "2", cash_discount_amount: "300", cash_discount_percentage: "7"}
```

My question is this: how come the variable "this_product_total" skips the first JSON result object when it is smaller that the variable "amount" in the "if" statement? when I console.log(amount), the log shows 1000, 300 and 200 when the text, in variable "this_product_total" is 512.89? The values in "amount" and "thid_product_total" are true when I evaluated them with $.isNumeric(); Please help.

Comment: 512 is clearly not `>=` to 1000. Also if more than one item does meet condition you will over write the text each time

Comment: @charlietfl so how do I make it match only say, 300?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this is that the amount "1000" was treated as a string. So I had to parseInt(amount) and the 1000 problem is solved and I added a break; to the if(this_product_total >= amount) so that once it found the 1st matching condition, it stops looping ...

Comment: don't forget to add the `radix` parameter!  `parseInt(amount, 10)`

Comment: also, that `break` won't do anything in a `$.each` function because it's not a real loop.  You have to `return false` inside a `$.each` callback to stop the iteration.